# Identifying I2C to dual UART interface IC part number of DFRobot module

Tags: arduino, identification, i2c, uart

DFRobot has a nice I2C to dual UART adapter module [DFR0627](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity%3A%20IIC%20to%20Dual%20UART%20Module%20SKU%3A%20DFR0627) and good Arduino library support.

[image]
[image]

I am going to design a customized PCB with several hight speed UART based on Arduino + DFR0627 configuration.
But on their wiki page and schematic, I could not find any part number of the 16-pin SSOP packaged IC.

Could anyone help me identifying this IC's part number?

Comment: A high-res image on [amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Gravity%EF%BC%9AIIC-Dual-UART-Module-Multiple-Converter-Expander/dp/B0869L58ZG) lets us see something like `WK2132`, and it is confirmed by comment in the code  [here](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_IICSerial). But it is rather hard to find otherwise, so it might be not it's real PN

Comment: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Interface-Specialized_WEIKAI-WK2132-ISSG_C401039.html

Comment: It's all in Chinese except the numbers and some signal wire names. But, surprisingly readable...https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_WEIKAI-WK2132-ISSG_C401039.pdf

Comment: Thank you, @GTElectronics
That workes!

Comment: If you need multiple UARTs, just use a single microcontroller with enough UARTs instead of multiple WK2132 chips. It will likely be faster and larger than the Arduino so you could simply leave out the Arduino too.

Comment: Noted. But for my current project, Using the existing Arduino library on ESP32 is important. We don't want to add another MCU aside of ESP32. That's why I was looking for I2C to UART expander.

Comment: Questions about Arduino tools and libraries are more suited for https://arduino.stackexchange.com/.